# Help understanding a proof that $f(x) = 1/x$ is not uniform continuous on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that $f(x) = 1/x$ is not uniform continuous on $(0,\infty

)$. The proof uses the mean value theorem.

We have that $|f(x)-f(y)|< |f'(c)||x-y|$ where $c$ is between $x$ and $y$. To get $|f'(c)||x-y| <\epsilon$ we need $|x-y|<\frac{\epsilon}{|f'(c)|}$ and $f'(c) \rightarrow 0$ as $x,y\rightarrow 0$. Thus the choice of delta in the definition of the continuity cannot be made independently of $x,y$.

I don't understand the last part. I get why $|f'(c)|\rightarrow 0$, because $x$ and $y$ are coming closer and closer together. But why does this mean that the choice of $\delta$ cannot be made independently of $x,y$?

Comment: If you are proving something on $(0,1)$, then saying $x\to\infty$ makes no sense. I think you probably misunderstood what the proof is about.

Comment: You mean $f'(c) \to \infty$ as $x,y \to 0$

Comment: The interval is meant to be $(0,\infty)$, also both are meant to be 0 @Omnomnomnom

Comment: They are not both meant to be zero.  As $x \to 0$, $|f'(x)| \to \infty$.

Comment: Is that then perhaps a mistake in the textbook? I just double checked and that's what it says.

Comment: The explosive behavior that makes it not uniformly continuous occurs near 0, it should not be uniformly continuous on any $(0,b)$, $b>0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a suspicious-looking argument, dangerously close to (if not actually asserting) the false implication, "If $f$ is differentiable on $(0, \infty)$ and $f'$ is unbounded, then $f$ is not uniformly continuous." (The square root function on has unbounded derivative but is uniformly continuous on $(0, \infty)$.)

More convincing arguments for the reciprocal function include:

1. The sequence $(\frac{1}{n})$ is Cauchy, but the image sequence $(n)$ is not.
2. If $x$ and $y$ are positive, then
   $$
   \left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\right| = \frac{|y - x|}{xy},
   $$
   and the right-hand side is unbounded on every interval $(0, \delta)$.